# Ошибка в коде с++

Tags: c++

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int d[100];
    fstream read("c:\\input.txt",ios::in);
    fstream write("c:\\output.txt",ios::out);

    read >> d;
    write << d;

    return 0;
}
```

в чем ошибка?

Comment: Какую ошибку выводит компилятор?

Comment: Может d слишком мал?

Comment: @vladx555, IMHO операторы '<<' и '>>' не определены для **массива**.

Comment: Компилятор какой?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int d;
    fstream read("c:\\input.txt",ios::in);
    fstream write("c:\\output.txt",ios::out);

    read >> d;
    write << d;

    return 0;
}
```

fstream можно записать(прочитать) число(int), а не целочисленный массив (int*). В данном случаи нужно записать каждый элемент массива по отдельности, например так

```
int d[100];
fstream read("c:\\input.txt",ios::in);
fstream write("c:\\output.txt",ios::out);

for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    read >> d[i];
}

for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    write << d[i];
}

return 0;
```